# Export UDO to XML on SAP B1

Tags: sapb1

I want to export the UDOs and its predefined forms to XML on SAP B1 client.

Is it possible on SAP B1 client? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do it through the SAP Business One Interface. You will have to use DI API.

```
SAPbobsCOM.UserObjectsMD oUDO = (SAPbobsCOM.UserObjectsMD)SBOSharedConnection.oCompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oUserObjectsMD);
oUDO.GetByKey(code);
oUDO.GetAsXML();
```

Answer (score 0):

if your DB have screenprinter then you can also export the UDO through the UI [image: Screenpainter]